# control user gesture on my map

Tags: android, google-maps, gesture

I new in coding google map, 
my question is how i control the user gestur drag , zoom in and zoom out.
because my code always back to the current location of user when i zoomin/out, nad when i drag/ scroll up, down, left, right. always back to the current possition .

its my code for current loc user

```
private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16));
        }
    };
```

Comment: Simply remove `mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16));`

Comment: if i remove that code, my app cant directly go to the user current possition. i want when the app open , the camera go to user current location, but still can move the map camera, like drag scrool zoomin/out with out come back to user current loc,

Comment: So, you want the map to center on your current location only the first time?

Comment: @antonio how? can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `boolean` to move the camera only the first time:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker mMarker;
    private boolean firstTime = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));

        if (firstTime) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16));
            firstTime = false;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: Take into account that this example uses `GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener` only because that is the method that you are using in your question, but it's deprecated and you must use the FusedLocationProviderApi according to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#public-methods):

> **public final void setOnMyLocationChangeListener
>   (GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener listener)**
>
> This method was deprecated. use
>   com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi instead.
>   FusedLocationProviderApi provides improved location finding and power
>   usage and is used by the "My Location" blue dot. See the
>   MyLocationDemoActivity in the sample applications folder for example
>   example code, or the Location Developer Guide.

Comment: ok ill try it latter, thanks it before @antonio u are very helpfull

Comment: hai @antonio , i try your code but its still back to mycurrent locaton

Comment: Could you post the most relevant parts of your code?